# How to create Java annotation for a fake abstract method?

Tags: java, annotations, bridj

I say fake because the method isn't declared as abstract, but it doesn't have an implementation.

I'm trying to fix a bug introduced by using [BridJ](https://github.com/nativelibs4java/BridJ). BridJ uses a custom annotation to annotate a method inside of an Android Activity. The method has the following signature:

```
@Library("example")
public static void helloLog(Pointer<Byte> logThis);
```

But the compiler complains of `Missing method body, or declare abstract` on these two lines of code. So I decided to look at the source code for the annotation, which is:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR})
public @interface Library {

    /**
     * Name of this library.
     */
    String value();

    /**
     * Names of libraries that need to be loaded before this library is loaded
     */
    String[] dependencies() default {};

    String versionPattern() default "";
}
```

After reading up on [Java Custom Annotations](http://www.javatpoint.com/custom-annotation), I don't see anything wrong with the definition of the annotation. For the heck of it, I added an implementation to the `helloLog()` method.

```
public static void helloLog(Pointer<Byte> logThis) {}
```

After which the error goes away. I didn't expect it to fix the problem, but FWIW, it allows me to build and run, but it crashes on startup because of a `NullPointerException` that I plan on looking into.

**Update 1**

@thomas-kläger and others suggested adding the `native` keyword to `helloLog`. I tried that, but then I get this runtime error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void connectedsolutions.cummins.com.bridjtest.MainActivity.helloLog(org.bridj.Pointer) (tried Java_connectedsolutions_cummins_com_bridjtest_MainActivity_helloLog and Java_connectedsolutions_cummins_com_bridjtest_MainActivity_helloLog__Lorg_bridj_Pointer_2)
```

I will read up on the documentation and examples some more. Thanks.

Comment: Java does not allow non-abstract methods to have an empty body.

Comment: ...except if they are native methods: `public static native void helloLog(Pointer<Byte> logThis);`

Comment: ...or if the annotation is processed at compile time to add an empty body.

Comment: It sounds like that method should have the modifier `native` on it. Adding an empty body seems like it would preclude BridJ from knowing that anything needs to be done with that method during its compile-time code generation.

Comment: Thanks all. The `native` keyword makes sense, but then it complains about a ` No implementation found for...` error. I will update the post with more details and keep reading up on the BridJ documentation and examples.

Comment: ...except that this is not a `native` method.